# Can I put Button in Spinner

Tags: java, android

I can use String-array inside Spinner 
But i don't know if i can put anything else ?
I want to put some Button's in a Spinner but when i put some in XML , the application crashed !!

```
    <Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</Spinner>
```

Is this the Right way to do it 
Or what ???

Comment: one reason I think of is you have not given the id in button ..this is mandatory...

Comment: No ,,, i have just put the id 
and nothing happened

Comment: Please post your log

Comment: Dude there will be errors logged in IDE which you using. Please post it. I will suggest read upon android first if you asking this question

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work bgecause this is not the way that you place buttons in a spinner.

By Definition `Spinner` is a dropdown menu that can almost take any layout. First of all you have to decide how your spinner row will be.

e.g.:

If you would like to have 2 buttons you got to make a layout/spinner_row.xml file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and looks like:

[image: Result]

Then you got to make an adapter that adapts each row of the spinner with the data that you would like.